# Lista de raízes quadradas

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Como é que posso fazer uma função que receba um parâmetro `n`, que devolva uma lista das primeiras `n` raízes quadradas, utilizando funções de ordem superior, em Python.

Como abaixo demonstrado:

```
[sqrt(1), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2)+sqrt(3), ...]
```

Já tentei fazer assim desta forma:

```
return sum([x**0.5 for x in range(1,n+1)])
```

Mas não me dá o que quero, dá-me apenas a soma das `n` raízes.

Comment: "Utilizando funções de ordem superior" é uma restrição, uma exigencia ou uma opção?

Comment: @Sidon No que estou a fazer é uma exigência, é necessário usar as funções de ordem superior

Comment: @Sidon Para a seguinte como é que posso fazer com que uma função que receba uma função, uma lista e um elemento , devolva todos os estados intermédios do acumulador na forma de uma lista. Isto é, por exemplo, uma funcao(lambda acum, x: acum + x, [2, 4, 6], 0) --> [0, 2, 6, 12]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) não é necessário, para retornar a lista, simplesmente faça:

```
import math

def raiz(n):
  return [math.sqrt(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]

print (raiz(6))
# [1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178]
```

<sub>[**`DEMO`**](https://repl.it/HBmf)</sub>

Uma outra alternativa com [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

```
def raiz(n):
  return list(map(math.sqrt, range(1, n + 1)))
```

Comment: Obrigada já consegui graças à sua ajuda!

Comment: @py_9, Mas pelo seu texto, parece que essa solução nao esta atendendo, ou eu entendi errado? quando voce menciona: [sqrt(1), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2)+sqrt(3), ...] fica parecendo que o resultado que vc  espera é uma lista em que cada elemento é a somatoria da sqr(n) atual com a sqrs dos n anteriores, ou seja, o ultimo elemento seria a somatira de todos. Ou eu entendi errado ou vc se expressou mal.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai a resposta para o que eu entendi da questão, pelo fragmento de texto colocado na pergunta:

> Como abaixo demonstrado: 
>   [sqrt(1), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2), sqrt(1)+sqrt(2)+sqrt(3), ...]

Fica claro que o resultado esperado seria uma lista em que cada elemento é o resultado da raiz do elemento n somado aos resultados das raízes de cada n anterior, assim, o resultado para um range de 1 a 4 seria:

```
[1.0, 2.414213562373095, 4.146264369941973, 6.146264369941973]
```

Onde, o primeiro elemento á a raiz de 1, o segundo é a soma da raiz de 1 
mais a raiz de 2, o terceiro, a soma da raiz de 1 + a raiz de 2 + a raiz de 3 e, finalmente, o ultimo seria a soma dos 3 primeiros elementos + a raiz de 4, ou
seja, o ultimo elemento seria exatamente o resultado da primeira
tentativa expressada no texto da questão:

```
return sum([x**0.5 for x in range(1,n+1)])
```

Se n for igual a 4 o resultado esperado (de acordo com o texto)     teria que ser:

```
[1.0, 2.414213562373095, 4.146264369941973, 6.146264369941973]
```

Levando essa abordagem em consideração desenvolvi 2 funções, uma sem o uso de funções de alta ordem e a outra utilizando-as.

Abaixo o código em que é utilizado a função map combinada com lambda:

```
# Utilizando Funcoes de alta ordem
def sum_sqr_high(n,dt):
    current = sqrt(n)+dt['last']
    dt['list_sqr'].append(current)
    dt['last'] = current

data = {'last': 0, 'list_sqr': []}
list(map(lambda n: sum_sqr_high(n, data), [n for n in range(1,5)]))

print ('Com alta ordem ',data['list_sqr'])    
Com alta ordem  [1.0, 2.414213562373095, 4.146264369941973, 6.146264369941973]
```

Abaixo o código sem a utilização das funções de alta ordem:

```
# Sem alta orde
def sqrn(_n):
    last=0
    list_sqr = []
    for n in range(1, _n+1):
        current = sqrt(n)+last
        list_sqr.append(current)
        last = current
    return list_sqr 

print('Sem alta ordem: ',sqrn(4))
Sem alta ordem:  [1.0, 2.414213562373095, 4.146264369941973, 6.146264369941973]
```

[Clique para ver o código rodando](https://repl.it/HBmf/8)

Comment: Para a seguinte como é que posso fazer com que uma função que receba uma função, uma lista e um elemento , devolva todos os estados intermédios do acumulador na forma de uma lista. Isto é, por exemplo, uma funcao(lambda acum, x: acum + x, [2, 4, 6], 0) [0, 2, 6, 12

Comment: @py_9 Poderia elaborar mais a pergunta? não consegui entender o que voce quer nesse comentário